# Set focus to an application with batch

Tags: excel, batch-file

I'm using WinXP and I have a batch script where I determine the filename of an Excel sheet and then launch it by simply launching that Excel sheet.

The problem is that Excel is running at that time. So when the batch file launches the Excel sheet, Excel is sent to front and the Excel sheet opens. However, the focus still is on the DOS-box where the batch file is running.

How do I set the focus to the Excel sheet in this situation?

Comment: what's the current command that you are using to accomplish this? Just `filename`?

Comment: @Mechaflash yes, just the `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the file directly to Excel:

```
excel.exe "C:\Path\To\file.xlsx"
```

Can't test as we use open office.

EDIT:

```
START /B (excel.exe "C:\Path\To\file.xlsx")
```

Comment: I tried that, but it opens another Excel application window. I already checked the command line parameters, but there doesn't seem to be a switch to reuse an existing application window.

Comment: Tools > Options > View tab, and look for "Windows in Taskbar". Uncheck that and try it.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is try using `START /B (excel.exe "C:\Path\To\file.xlsx")` Maybe even try the `/MAX` switch to see if that makes a difference for focus.

Comment: While it indeed does not open another Excel application window, the focus still remains in the DOS-box. Note that it only works without the parentheses. --- I wish I could give you some reputation for the constructive inputs, but if I up-vote your answer or comments it would mean something else.

Comment: =( . Tis okay. If it doesn't solve the problem then don't upvote. I hope someone else can answer or you find your answer. It's quite possible you may have to use powershell or vbscript to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus another program you can do this.

```
call :focus WindowTitle
exit /b

:focus
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

    if ["%~1"] equ [""] (
        echo Please give the window's title.
        exit /b
    )

    set pr=%~1
    set pr=!pr:"=!

    echo CreateObject("wscript.shell").appactivate "!pr!" > "%tmp%\focus.vbs"
    call "%tmp%\focus.vbs"
    del "%tmp%\focus.vbs"

goto :eof 
endlocal
```

I am using vbscript to focus the application. You need to pass the window's title, not the window's name (whatever.bat). To make sure you get the right