# BATCH - Steam Window

Tags: windows, batch-file, steam

So I've been working on my personal Steam account swapper with pre-game choice options but, I've been running into a few problems. The program works fine but I'm getting this problem where when I chose which profile I want logon to (for smurfing purposes) the Steam window pops up in my face and it prevents me from being able to choose which game I want to play. So I was wondering if there's a way to close the Steam window (and only the window) as soon as it pops up. **taskkilling** it won't work because if you taskkill it right away it will close the login (login starts when I choose which account I want to play on)

TL;DR I want to close steam window as soon as it pops up

**NOTE: When logging in, task manager reads the steam logon window as SteamLogin and not Steam** Not sure if this would make the lightbulb go off.

Answer (score 0):

In steam there is an option to suppress the login prompt on system boot, I am not 100% if this will work with your loginswitcher, but is worth a try.

Go to "start menu", "run", type "regedit".
In the registry editor, expand the tree until you find this HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
In "Run", you will find all applications that are starting with Windows. Edit the value for "Steam" and add the silent option (-silent).
Reboot and try your login switcher.

Comment: -silent is there be default :(

Comment: -silent made it half work, it still tabs me out of my menu, any ideas? is there a way how to switch task (alt+tab) into the command prompt window?

Comment: You could try something similar to what was explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494977/set-focus-to-an-application-with-batch